# Sublimetext 2, Rails, Haml :: color coding of rails methods in .haml files fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, package, haml, sublimetext2

I'm playing with Sublimetext2 for development of a Rails app (switching from Textmate). I'm experiencing a problem with color coding of rails methods in my .haml files. The files with .haml extension are set to open with Ruby Haml bundle copied from Textmate. The issue appears in any of the color themes I tried.

So, for example, in a file:

_form.html.haml

```
= form_for @object do |f|
  f.label ...
  f.text_field ...
  ...
```

the keywords "form_for", "label", "text_field" should be red (when using Railscast theme). But they are white.

It doesn't seem to be an issue with the Railscasts theme since the problem (not color coding rails methods) exists in all themes in .haml files.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Thanks,
martin

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try different package for haml - https://github.com/n00ge/sublime-text-haml-sass

Comment: I tried as many different HAML bundles (packages) as I found, the one you suggested among them. Doesn't do it. Incidentally, the package I'm using color codes :javascript inside "-content_for" in Sublimetext, the others I tried do not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shortcoming in the HAML file.  Here's the fix:

```
    diff --git a/Packages/Rails/Ruby Haml.tmLanguage b/Packages/Rails/Ruby Haml.tmLanguage
    index 88d43f2..8bf14a4 100644
    --- a/Packages/Rails/Ruby Haml.tmLanguage       
    +++ b/Packages/Rails/Ruby Haml.tmLanguage       
    @@ -90,7 +90,7 @@
                                    </dict>
                            </dict>
                            <key>end</key>
    -                       <string>$|(?!\.|#|\{|\[|=|-|~|/)</string>
    +                       <string>$|(?!\.|#|\{|\[|(?:!?=)|-|~|/)</string>
                            <key>patterns</key>
                            <array>
                                    <dict>
    @@ -199,7 +199,7 @@
                    <key>rubyline</key>
                    <dict>
                            <key>begin</key>
    -                       <string>=|-|~</string>
    +                       <string>(?:!?=)|-|~</string>
                            <key>contentName</key>
                            <string>source.ruby.embedded.haml</string>
                            <key>end</key>
```

I'm not sure how to get that upstreamed however.  Here's my original post: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10246

Comment: Actually, that patch fixes '!='.  '=' should work out of the box (I'm on build 2217).  Does '-' highlight Ruby code properly for you?

Comment: Yes, '-' highlights properly, '=' does not.